# named only one column of many data frame within a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rename

I have a list with 7 Data Frame, everyone has the same columns ("DATE", "PRECIPITACION"), so I want rename only the second column ("PRECIPITACION") in an ascending way, i.e. PRECIPITACION_1, PRECIPITACION_2,....,PRECIPITACION_7, I try this

```
my.files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
my.files <- mixedsort(my.files)
my.data <- lapply(my.files,
              read.csv,
              header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

for my particular DF:

```
data.Precip <- rbind(my.data)[1:7]
```

and for rename the second column:

```
colnames(data.Precip[[1]]) = paste(colnames(data.Precip[[1]]), "1", sep = "_")
```

but this code above is only for individual data frame

any idea for this ?

Comment: `rbind` as you have it is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for statement to set the sequential name with the current loop index and then update the second column using the column number (not sure if that is what you meant to do):

```
for(i in 1:length(data.Precip))
    colnames(data.Precip[[i]])[2] = paste(colnames(data.Precip[[i]])[2], i, sep = "_")
```

Comment: yes, it´s what I wanted, now, to see full DF don´t appear the change in the names of second columns, but visualizing each DF separately if, any idea of why this happens. Thanks for you help

Comment: yes, this code worked perfectly, but, now make this for other 3 Data Frames within a same list, but other column name. i.e, the secod DF have a two columns ("DATE", "RADIACION"), so I want rename only the second column ("RADIACION") in an ascending way but iinitiate of 8, i.e. "RADIACION_8", "RADIACION_9"..."RADIACION_14", many idea for this ? Thanks